# How to change IIS 7 application settings using C#

Tags: c#, iis, iis-7

I have deployed an application to the IIS 7 Default Website. To make changes to application's settings, I have to right-click the application, go to `Manage Application`, and click `Advance Settings`.  In the window that pops up (in the `Behavior` section), there is a `Enabled protocols` which is set to `http` by default.  I want to change this to `http,net.tcp` using C#.

Comment: From within your website, or from a separate program?